# Writing a simple function which sets up google map marker on button click

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have written a simple function which onclick should add marker to the google map. Here is the code for the js file

```
function setupMapArea() {

var default_latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.5072, 0.1275);
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: default_latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    draggable: false,
    scrollwheel: false,
    zoomControl: false,
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("google-map"), myOptions);

mapBooking = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-container"), myOptions);
function setupMarkerWaypoint(){

console.log('setting waypoint marker');
waypointMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: default_latlng,
  map: mapBooking,
  icon:"http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png"
});
waypointMarker.setVisible(false);
}
```

The code for the index.html file is

```
<input id="AddWaypoint" name="AddWaypoint" type="button" value="Add Waypoint" onclick="setupMarkerWaypoint()"
```

On clicking the button the marker doesn't show up. I am trying to make a simple marker like [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple) to prop up on clicking button. What changes should I make ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setupMarkerWaypoint` only exists within the scope of `setupMapArea`, so your event listener has no access to it. Try this:

```js
var mapBooking, default_latlng;

document.getElementById('AddWaypoint').addEventListener('click', setupMarkerWaypoint);

function setupMapArea() {
    default_latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.5072, 0.1275);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: default_latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        draggable: false,
        scrollwheel: false,
        zoomControl: false,
    };

    mapBooking = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-container"), myOptions);
}

function setupMarkerWaypoint(){
    console.log('setting waypoint marker');
    waypointMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: default_latlng,
        map: mapBooking,
        icon:"http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png"
    });
}

setupMapArea();
```

```css
#map-container {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<input id="AddWaypoint" name="AddWaypoint" type="button" value="Add Waypoint">
<div id="map-container"></div>
```

Comment: @ Josh Bjelovuk : I changed it to true. Removed the line from code. I don't see any difference.

Comment: I have added a mapBooking variable which is a map container (after var map - edited)

Comment: Thanks for working it out, actually your previous answer was correct i.e. waypointMarker.setVisible(false) should be set to true.

Comment: I would like to drag my marker, I am trying google event handler but the marker doesn't move, any inputs ?

Comment: Get rid of `draggable: false`.

Comment: Thanks for that. I want my marker to display the location in an infowindow by reverse geocoding(taking latitude and longitude), any idea for that ?